# Conect Azure Api Management with Azure Function only with Private endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-private-link

I have a Virtual Network (Vnet) with a Subnet (SVnet) inside the Vnet, I have a private Api Management (Apim) with a Private Endpoint associated with SVnet and a private Azure Function (AzFunc) with a Private Endpoint associated with SVnet.

It is important to clarify that both Apim and AzFucn are not directly connected to the Vnet, nor to the SVnet, they only have Private Endpoints to the SVnet.

¿Can the Apim access the AzFunc resource with this configuration?

¿Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that Apim and the Azure Func have Private Endpoints associated with the same subnet *SVnet*, they can communicate with each other over the private network.

Created virtual network with subnet like below:

[image]

Created Azure API Management private endpoint with same virtual network like below:

[image]

[image]

Now I created function app with same `SVnet` like below:

[image]

Both the Apim and the AzFunc have Private Endpoints connected to the same subnet (SVnet) they can communicate with each other over the private network. The Private Endpoint for the Apim will resolve to an IP address within the subnet, and the Private Endpoint for the AzFunc will also resolve to an IP address within the same subnet.

Created vm with same vnet when I check the endpoints it resolves successfully like below:

[image]